# Retrieving IIS 6.0 certificate information in .NET

Tags: c#, iis, certificate

How to get information about certificate installed on iis 6.0 server under C# in winforms application.

Answer (score 1):

**UPD** I just noticed that you need C# but not ASP.NET, so my reply is not correct. You can use [System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525791.aspx) to query IIS properties. Please note that certificate is not bound to the whole IIS server. Every web site can have it's own certificate.

Comment: Thanks but I forgot to mention that it is winform application.

Comment: Yes I use DirectoryEntry, however I can't find field in IIS metabase that give information about certificate.